# How does PHP choose what email address it sends from?

Tags: php, linux, apache, email, webserver

I noticed something odd while doing some testing on someone's development server. Using a *very* simple mail test...

```
mail('iAmNotSharingMy@email.com', 'test subject', 'test message');
```

...on receipt, sometimes the sender is `root@` and other times the sender is `www-data@`.

What causes this to change, seemingly, randomly?

Yes, I know the sender can be set in the headers, but I am curious as to what causes the default behavior.

#### Server Information

> `Ubuntu Server 12.04` `Apache/2.2.22` `PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7`

#### In response to [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441427/how-does-php-choose-what-email-address-it-sends-from#comment47051309_29441427)

> `echo exec('whoami');` returns **www-data** as the user the web server is running under.

#### So, what would cause scripts to run as root instead of the web server user?

Comment: The default should be whatever username the webserver runs as. It can be overridden in `php.ini`.

Comment: Something must be causing those scripts to run as root instead. I'm not sure where to check for that.